# Count and group by date on multiple database tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Working on a report page that contains counts for certain columns from the last 10 ten days I got this to work in c# after multiple queries to the database but ran in to trouble on the date columns so I figured I'd try and write a stored procedure or a single query that returned all the results I needed but I've stressed myself enough and I'm not a SQL guru (this is not homework btw!)

I have 2 different tables in different databases that only have the date in (common) (sort -of) but the column names are different.

```
db1.order  
-----------  
c1    c2      c3      requestedshipping    dateadded
------------------------------------------------------
1    1.00    .95      ground            2013-05-15 18:34:48.867<-has time stamp in date
2    1.50    1.56     express           2013-05-15 18:34:48.867
3    .50     75       ground            2013-05-14 18:34:48.867
4    .50     75       ground            2013-05-14 18:34:48.867

db2.ship
-----------  
c1    c2         service               dateshipped
------------------------------------------------------
.25    1.00      ground            2013-05-15 00:00:00<-time stamp ?
2.3    1.50      express           2013-05-15 00:00:00
.36    .50       ground            2013-05-14 00:00:00
```

Trying to get results like

```
date       tot_order  tot_shipped  tot_express  tot_order_c3   tot_ship_c1   tot_ship_c2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2013-05-15   2           2            1           2.51           2.28          2.50
2013-05-14   2           1            0           150            .36           .50
```

**THINGS I'VE TRIED**
I was using these queries to get totals then comparing the dates in c# but with the time stamp numbers weren't matching up

```
SELECT TOP (10) DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, db1order.dateadded), 0) od,   COUNT(db1order.dateadded)
   FROM [db1].[dbo].[order] db1order 
   GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, db1order.dateadded), 0) 
   ORDER BY od DESC 



SELECT TOP (10) DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, db2ship.dateshipped), 0) od,   COUNT(db2ship.dateshipped)
   FROM [db2].[dbo].[ship] db2ship 
   GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, db2ship.dateshipped), 0) 
   ORDER BY od DESC
```

I saw a article about using UNION ALL but this unions the totals together.

```
select TOP (10) dt, count(*)
   from (select DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, dateadded), 0) AS dt from [db1].[dbo].   [order] union all
      select DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, dateshipped), 0) AS dt from [db2].[dbo].[ship]) v
group by dt
ORDER BY dt DESC
```

I seen a couple of articles about creating a temp table but no examples of how to get information like I want into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can union the results of the two tables in the same format within a Common Table Expression [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (a.k.a. CTE) , and add a "rowType" column to allow you to differentiate between an `order` vs. a `ship` row, and then perform your aggregates based on this.

```
;WITH cteCombined as
(
    SELECT 
          rowType = 0 --orders
        , [date] = convert(date, o.dateadded) 
        , o.c1
        , o.c2
        , o.c3
        , o.requestedshipping
    FROM [db1].[dbo].[order] o 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
          rowType = 1 --shipments
        , [date] = convert(date, s.dateshipped)
        , s.c1, s.c2
        , c3 = null
        , requestedshipping = s.[service]
    FROM [db2].[dbo].[ship] s
)
SELECT c.[date]
    , tot_order = sum(case when c.rowtype = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
    , tot_shipped = sum(case when c.rowtype = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
    --EDIT: based on expected results then tot_express appears to be only based on orders (with assumption that you will have an order prior to a shipment)
    , tot_express = sum(case when c.rowType = 0 AND c.requestedshipping = 'EXPRESS' then 1 else 0 end)
    , tot_order_c3 =  sum(case when c.rowtype = 0 then c.c3 else 0 end)
    , tot_ship_c1 =  sum(case when c.rowtype = 1 then c.c1 else 0 end)
    , tot_ship_c2 =  sum(case when c.rowtype = 1 then c.c2 else 0 end)
    /*etc...*/
FROM cteCombined c
GROUP BY c.[date]
;
```

Comment: For the `tot_*_c*` columns you're summing zeros and ones instead of the actual values of the columns

Comment: @Tom, no it isn't.  If it is the rowtype that we want (0=order, 1=shipment), then it sums the column value (i.e. `then c.c1`), else it sums a 0.

Comment: Both solutions worked for this problem, so I marked the first one by BateTech as answer since it had already received an up-vote. After reading articles cte's might be the solution to many of my SQL adventures.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two CTEs, one for the orders and one for the shipments, and then join the two.  I wasn't sure how you wanted to handle `express` though -- where does that value come from?  In the example below, I used the service column from the shipments table, not the orders table, because based on your example you're only summing one of them.

See [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed5e8/6)

```
;with orders AS (
  SELECT CAST(dateadded AS DATE) as [date],
        COUNT(*) AS tot_order, 
        SUM(o.c3) AS tot_order_c3
  FROM tblOrder o
  GROUP BY CAST(dateadded AS DATE)
),
shipments AS (
  SELECT CAST(dateshipped AS DATE) as [date],
         COUNT(*) AS tot_shipped,
         SUM(CASE WHEN service = 'express' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tot_express,
         SUM(c1) AS tot_ship_c1,
         SUM(c2) AS tot_ship_c2
  FROM tblShip
  GROUP BY CAST(dateshipped AS DATE)
)
SELECT ISNULL(s.[date], o.[date]) as [date],
       ISNULL(o.tot_order, 0) as tot_order,
       ISNULL(s.tot_shipped, 0) as tot_shipped,
       ISNULL(s.tot_express, 0) as tot_express,
       ISNULL(o.tot_order_c3, 0) as tot_order_c3,
       ISNULL(s.tot_ship_c1, 0) as tot_ship_c1,
       ISNULL(s.tot_ship_c2, 0) as tot_ship_c2
FROM shipments s
FULL JOIN orders o ON s.[date] = o.[date]
```

Comment: This version will not list orders that have 0 shipments on a given date, or vice versa.  You would possibly need to do a `full outer join` if there could be orders without shipments or shipment without orders on a given date, which seems like a likely scenario.

Comment: Noted... I've changed the answer to support nulls in either table